# Flutter: Reading file is failing

Tags: flutter, dart, readfile

I checked for typos. I have the file in pubspec.yaml assets section. I cannot understand why it can't find the file which is not empty.

Error message:

Performing hot restart... Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome... Restarted application in 337ms. Error while trying to load an asset: Flutter Web engine failed to fetch >"assets/assets/rungFile.txt". HTTP request succeeded, but the server responded with HTTP >status 404. Error: Unable to load asset: "assets/rungFile.txt". The asset does not exist or has empty data.

```
void readFile() async {
           String data = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/rungFile.txt');
           List<String> lines = const LineSplitter().convert(data);
           for (String line in lines) {
           List<String> words = line.split(',');
          Rung rung = Rung(name: words[0], rungId: words[1], done: bool.parse(words[2]), 
           boldTitle: bool.parse(words[3]), info: words[4]);
           Rung.myList.add(rung);
                        }
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarted Android Studio. Problem went away.